# Round a number an keep zero in php

Tags: php

With PHP I round a number:

```
round(1.30, 2)
```

But I have `1.3` whereas I need `1.30`.

How it is possible please ?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to look at `sprintf()`

Comment: Or this, `number_format(round(1.30, 2), 2)`

Comment: you could use number_format($num,number of zero after decimal) PHP function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$unpadded = round(1.30,2);
$padded = sprintf('%0.2f', $unpadded);
```

Took suggestions from Rizier123.